# Find the selected ListView item and then perform an action on click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, .net-5

I tried this:

```
 If ListView1.SelectedItems = 1 Then
        'do somehting
    ElseIf ListView1.SelectedItems = 2 Then
        'do something else
    Else
        'do another thing
    End If
```

But It didn't work. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: The `SelectedItems` property is a collection and cannot be equal to an Integer. Are you trying to check the value of the ListItem's Text or the count of `SelectedItems` collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectedItems` property of the `ListView` control is a collection (of potentially multiple selected items).

Consider a situation where you have control ListView1, and manually add items to it in your form load event, like so:

```
ListView1.Items.Add("Dog")
ListView1.Items.Add("Cat")
ListView1.Items.Add("Bird")
```

Then you have a button control Button1 whose click event has the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s As String = ""
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        s += item.Text + vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox(s)
End Sub
```

When you click the button, it iterates through the collection of all selected items one at a time, accessing each item's `.Text` property and adding them to an output.

So, when you say, "Find the selected listview item", there can be multiple selected items, so perhaps you can explain a bit more exactly what you'd like to see happen with the click since the control has several possible applicable event types.  Ex. Click, ItemChecked, MouseClick, MouseDoubleClick, etc.

UPDATE:  I may be misunderstanding your question.  Please provide more detail.

Perhaps this is what you're after?

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged
    If e.Item.Text = "Dog" Then MsgBox("It's a dog")
End Sub
```

Working with these events can be tricky.  For example that msgbox will pop up you select dog.  But it also pops when the selection changes from dog to something else, because that's still a selection changed event.  However this should get you going in the right direction.  You may need to look through the different events closely to figure out which one's going to work best for your situation - and you may need to handle multiple events.